# Python search for a start hex string, save the hex string after that to a new file

Tags: python

PYTHON

I would like to open a text file, search for a HEX pattern that starts with 45 3F, grab the following hex 6 HEX values, for example 45 4F 5D and put all this in a new file. I also know that it always ends with 00 00.

So the file can look like: bla bla sdsfsdf 45 3F 08 DF 5D 00 00 dsafasdfsadf 45 3F 07 D3 5F 00 00 xztert

And should be put in a new file like this:
08 DF 5D 
07 D3 5F

How can I do that?

I have tried:

```
output = open('file.txt','r')
my_data = output.read()
print re.findall(r"45 3F[0-9a-fA-F]", my_data)
```

but it only prints:

[]

Any suggestions?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Yor example data has a space after the `3F`, your regex doesn't permit that.

Comment: Your regex also only looks for a single character. You want to use `'45 3F ([0-9A-F]{2} [0-9A-F]{2} [0-9A-F]{2})'`.

Comment: does this file have binary data or are the hex values in ASCII (i.e. a text file)? because those are two different things.

Comment: Everything works now, thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete answer (Python 3):

```
with open('file.txt') as reader:
    my_data = reader.read()

matches = re.findall(r"45 3F ([0-9A-F]{2} [0-9A-F]{2} [0-9A-F]{2})", my_data)
data_to_write = " ".join(matches)
with open('out.txt', 'w') as writer:
    writer.write(data_to_write)
```

`re.findall` returns the capturing group, so there's no need to clear out '45 3F'.

When dealing with files, use `with open` so that the file descriptor will be released when indentation ends.

if you want to accept the first two octets dynamically:

```
search_string = raw_input()
regex_pattern = search_string.upper() + r" ([0-9A-F]{2} [0-9A-F]{2} [0-9A-F]{2})"
matches = re.findall(regex_pattern, my_data)
```

Comment: Hi again, is there anyone who knows how I can define the search/pattern value from terminal, and the use this value to find the wanted HEX?
I tried like this: 
print "Enter the string that comes before the wanted value in logfile: "
search_string = raw_input()
and then:
matches = re.findall(r'(search_string) ([0-9A-F]{2} [0-9A-F]{2} [0-9A-F]{2})', my_data)
but it does not work. Any thoughts please? Thank you

Comment: I edited the answer with a solution to a dynamic input. Don't forget to mark the answer as the accepted one if it helped you out :)

Comment: Is marked as accepted now? I am not quite sure were I do that, but I pressed the up arrow and the V sign.